# Firefox fires on choose, not on change

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, file-upload, input

Consider this:

```
<input type="file" id="filePicker">
<script>
    document.getElementById('filePicker').onchange = function() {
        alert('Hi!');
    };
</script>
```

Even if you choose the same file and the `filePicker` value doesn't change, you'll see the alert box in Firefox. Any solutions?

Comment: Just keep the previous value somewhere and compare - if it's same as the new one, ignore.

Comment: Just keep a record of the filename in a variable and check to see if the new value is the same as the old one. If it's not, run the code.

Comment: @Piskvor: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Andy: Would you mind providing an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temporary variable to hold the name of the filename that you can check the next time you select a file:

```
var filenameTemp = null;
document.getElementById('filePicker').onchange = function(e) {
  var filename = e.target.value;
  if (filename !== filenameTemp) {
    filenameTemp = filename;
    console.log('OK');
    // other code
  } else {
    console.log('Not OK')
  }
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/zajqv8qe/8/)

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run the snippet below. It will say "New File!" when there is a new file for both Chrome and Firefox.

```js
var previousFile = {};

function isSame(oldFile, newFile) {
  return oldFile.lastModified === newFile.lastModified &&
    oldFile.name === newFile.name &&
    oldFile.size === newFile.size &&
    oldFile.type === newFile.type;
} 

document.getElementById('filePicker').onchange = function () {
  var currentFile = this.files[0];
  
  if (isSame(previousFile, currentFile) === false) {
    alert('New File!');
    previousFile = currentFile;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filePicker">
```